# If $f$ is convex function and $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.When is $f$ continuous at $a$ and $b$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. We know that if $f$ is convex function then $f$ is continuous in $(a,b)$. Ιn which cases is $f$ continuous at $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do, without knowing more about $f$, is say that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ if $f(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and likewise for $f(b)$. For example, consider $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(0)=1$, $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$ for $x>0$. Then f is convex on $[0,1]$ but $f$ is not continuous at its left endpoint.

Comment: You can have convex functions that either are or aren’t continuous at their endpoints as both answers have shown so knowing only that a function is convex, the best you can do is say it’s continuous at its endpoints when it’s continuous at its endpoints.

Comment: Yes , i undestrand what you mean.Anyway in your example you take f:[0,1)→R but we must show for f:[0,1]→R to take this as example

Comment: I up voted your answer because of that last statement you made in the comment!

Comment: @ChrisRafael right, my bad, it should be $[0,1]$

Comment: Also, thanks! @RRL

Comment: Should’ve been in my answer from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

First, if $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$ then **finite or infinite** limits $\lim_{x \to a+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to b-} f(x)$ always exist.

Consider the functions $f:x \mapsto x^2$ on $[0,1]$ and

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}f(x), & 0 \leqslant x < 1,\\ 2, & x= 1 \end{cases}$$

Both are convex, but $f$ is continuous at $x=1$ and $g$ is not.

What does this tell you?

The one-sided limit at an endpoint is always a finite number or $\pm \infty$.  The limit cannot fail to exist (as with an oscillating function).  As long as limits are not infinite, the function may or may not be continuous at the endpoints, but it can be made continuous by changing values to match the one-sided limits.

Comment: Can you tell me one exaple with only f  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "example with only $f$"?

Comment: An example with only one function

Comment: Your question was in which cases is $f$ continuous at $a$ and $b$.  Between the two posts here you have the answer to that.  If $f(x) \to \pm \infty$ as $x \to b-$ then it is not only discontinuous at $x = b$, but the discontinuity can never be removed. If $f(x) \to c \neq \pm \infty$, then $f$ may or may not be continuous at $b$. It will be continuous if $f(b) = c$.